# Send Message to API in APIM from Azure Service Bus using Function App

Tags: c#, azure-functions, httprequest, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there a way to send a payload that is received on the service buss queue to be sent to an API in APIM using function app? I'm planning to do this on the ServiceBusTrigger function. I already have the message/payload on the QueueMessage, I just need to directly call the API and send the value of the QueueMessage to the API

```
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("sbq-messagequery", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
    QueueMessage queueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queueItem);
        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {data}");
        log.LogWarning($"Id = {queueItem.Payload}");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do an HttpRequest in your Trigger method.

Please find advice for using the HttpClient in Azure Functions [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection)

```
        [FunctionName("MyHttpTrigger")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("https://microsoft.com");
        var message = _service.GetMessage();

        return new OkObjectResult("Response from function with injected dependencies.");
    }
```

In your case it might be a POST request:

```
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("sbq-messagequery", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] QueueMessage queueItem, ILogger log)
{
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queueItem);
    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {data}");
    log.LogWarning($"Id = {queueItem.Payload}");

    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://yourtarget/api/lorem");
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queueItem.Payload);
    requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = _client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
}
```

Comment: Then would I call that method inside the Service Bus trigger?

Comment: @kebs yes, you have to do the HttpRequest inside the Service Bus trigger

Comment: Thanks for that, but one more thing, apologies i'm very new to this. I'm gonna create a separate method/function for the httprequest right? coz I can't have 2 triggers in one function but i'm not familiar on how to call tan async task inside the service bus trigger, could you post a basic example of that. Thank you

Comment: You have to do the request in the ServiceBusTrigger. Please find updated code in the answer